# Tidymodels + Spark

Tags: r, sparklyr, tidymodels

I'm trying to develop a simple logistic regression model using Tidymodels with the Spark engine.  My code works fine when I specify `set_engine = "glm"`, but fails when I attempt to set the engine to `spark`.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)
library(tidymodels)
```

```
train.df <- titanic::titanic_train

train.df <- train.df %>% 
  mutate(Survived = factor(ifelse(Survived == 1, 'Y', 'N')),
         Sex = factor(Sex),
         Pclass = factor(Pclass))

skimr::skim(train.df)
```

```
# Just working with Spark locally.

sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local', version = '3.1')

train.spark.df <- copy_to(sc, train.df)
```

```
logistic.regression.recipe <- 
  recipe(Survived ~ PassengerId + Sex + Age + Pclass, data = train.spark.df) %>%
  update_role(PassengerId, new_role = 'ID') %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_impute_linear(all_predictors())

logistic.regression.recipe
summary(logistic.regression.recipe)
```

```
logistic.regression.model <- 
  logistic_reg() %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("spark")

logistic.regression.model
```

```
logistic.regression.workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(logistic.regression.recipe) %>% 
  add_model(logistic.regression.model)

logistic.regression.workflow
```

```
logistic.regression.final.model <- 
  logistic.regression.workflow %>% 
  fit(data = train.spark.df)

logistic.regression.final.model
```

```
Error: `data` must be a data.frame or a matrix, not a tbl_spark.
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm guessing from the error message that it expects the data frame as is, before converting it to spark table. So, in your code, you can skip this line `train.spark.df <- copy_to(sc, train.df)` and use `train_df` in the `fit()` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the support for Spark in tidymodels is not even across all the parts of a modeling analysis. The support for *modeling* in [parsnip](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/) is good, but we don't have fully featured support for feature engineering in [recipes](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/) or putting those building blocks together in [workflows](https://workflows.tidymodels.org/). So for example, you can fit just the logistic regression model:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(sparklyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'sparklyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     invoke
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
train_sp <- copy_to(sc, titanic::titanic_train, overwrite = TRUE)


log_spec <- logistic_reg() %>% set_engine("spark")

log_spec %>%
  fit(Survived ~ Sex + Fare + Pclass, data = train_sp)
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  5.1s 
#> Formula: Survived ~ Sex + Fare + Pclass
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)     Sex_male         Fare       Pclass 
#>  3.143731639 -2.630648858  0.001450218 -0.917173436
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

But you can't use recipes and workflows out of the box. You might consider trying [something like using `spark_apply()`](https://therinspark.com/distributed.html) but that may be a challenge at the current stage of maturity in tidymodels' integration with Spark.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me!

I really appreciate all the work you, Max, and others have done to develop, document, and share tidymodels!

Comment: Given a resampling scheme, would a proper workflow to use `spark_apply()` for each resample? And what role plays [registerDoSpark](https://spark.rstudio.com/packages/sparklyr/latest/reference/registerdospark) in all this?